# Rabbi's contract with non Jew purchasing Chometz

Tags: passover, legal-documents

I am interested in studying the contract Rabbi's use to sell the Chometz to a non Jew prior to Pesach. Is there a link where I can see such a contract?

Comment: I am not talking about the contract one fills out when giving the Rabbi the right to sell for them the Chometz. I am talking about the contract the Rabbi presents to the Non Jew.

Comment: http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/chasidim/mchmz/12

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/8898

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8898&st=&pgnum=36&hilite=

Comment: there are many seforim with one. The kitsur, rav SA, noda beyuda  @GershonGold http://halachaed.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A5-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8.pdf